# Determine the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $T$ is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} $ be a function given by $T(x)=ax+b$ where $a,b$ are constants. Determine the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $T$ is a linear transformation.

I know that a linear transformation must meet the following criteria:
1) $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$
2) $T(ax)=aT(x)$

but how do I apply that criteria to solve my problem?

Comment: I guess $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ is enough for it to be a linear transformation. Indeed it is the equation of a straight line

Comment: @Euler_Salter "equation of a line" is not what is meant here and is scarcely what is meant in linear algebra; see the criteria from the question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom do you know how to work through this problem?

Comment: I know the definition of a linear transformation, but the equation of a line is a linear transformation, from what I recall. Takes an input and linearly gives an output

Comment: @Euler_Salter that is most certainly not the case.  They are *affine*, but not linear.  Note that $T(0) = 0$ for any linear transformation.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom   oh fair enough right ahah

Answer (score 2):

From the second axiom we get that a linear transformation must satisfy $T(0)=0$;
$$
T(0)=T(0\cdot1)=0\cdot T(1)=0.
$$
This tells you that, for $T$ to be linear, $b$ must be $0$, so $T$ must be of the form $T(x)=ax$. I leave it to you to check that a transformation like this is a linear transformation for every $a$.

Answer (score 2):

We have that $T(x) = ax+b$ for $a,b\in\mathbb R$.  Let's assume that any $a,b$ work and see if we can prove that it's a linear transformation.  If we can't prove it for some reason, then we'll try to make suitable restrictions on $a,b$ so we can.

We have that:
$$T(x+y) = a(x+y)+b = ax+ay+b = (ax+b)+(ay+b)-b = T(x)+T(y) -b$$
From this, we get the idea that $b = 0$ may be required.
Nevertheless, lets try to see what the other condition tells us:
$$T(cx) = a(cx)+b = cax+b = cax+cb-cb+b = cT(x)-cb+b$$
We again get that it works, if $b = 0$.
So, it seems that mandating that $b = 0$ and $a\in\mathbb R$ is enough to have $T$ be a linear transformation.